# Find index of location on grid when Tkinter Button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a toggle when the button is pressed but I cant seem to be able to get the index of the pressed button.

```
class Canvas_Grid(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, row = 8, column = 8):

        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title('Grid predictor')
        Frame.__init__(self, self.parent)
        self.pack(expand=True)
        self.canvas= Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.config(width = 1000,height = 1000)
        self.canvas.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'both')
        def Index_grabber():
            #here we are going to grab the index of the Button that was clicked
            pass
        self.Coordinates = []
        for x in range(row):
            for y in range(column):
                self.Coordinates += [(x, y, False)]
                Button(self.canvas, text = (False), height = 1, width = 2, bg = 'white', command = lambda:Index_grabber()).grid(row = x, column = y, padx = 0,pady = 0)


       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root= Tk()
    root.geometry('800x800')
    SizeX, SizeY = 10, 10
    cg=Canvas_Grid(root, row = SizeX, column = SizeY)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Index of the button as in how, the row and column position? That is basically `x` and `y`

Comment: That means it is the 81st button...? But OFC you will have to pass the current `x` and `y` onto the button callback to see it for each button rather than just the last buttons always (using parameters)

Comment: even if a different button is pressed x,y will returne 9,9

Comment: The duplicate question should solve the problem now